# Difference between EF.SqlServer and EF.SqlServerCompact

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to install `Entity Framework` in my `ASP.NET 5 MVC` project using `project.json`.

In the `dependencies` section I start typing `EntityFramework` and I only see 
`"EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact": "6.1.3"` instead of `"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "6.1.3"`.

What is the reason for this and what effects will this have?

Are there limitations in the compact version?

If I create a new ASP.NET 4 project with MVC and install `EntityFramework` then I see the `EntityFramework.SqlServer` reference installed and not the compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact` is for interacting with SQL CE. It's a single file based database. If you're dealing with MS SQL Server, that's definitely not what you want. You want `EntityFramwork` 6.1.3, there is no `EntityFramework.SqlServer`.